# Forbidden 403 sometimes (maybe htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

i have a problem with this site: http://accademiazeropiu.it .

Sometimes, when you change page or refresh the site (f5) I receive the error 403.

I'm trying to look at the code but the PHP side do not find anything strange.
I think it's a problem of privileges htaccess.

I post my code of htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^captcha - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ckfinder - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^class - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^control - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^css - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^fancy - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^fancybox - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^FlexSlider - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^font - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^images - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^img - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^include - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^js - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^mail - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^phpmailer - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^require - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^script_js - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^template - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^utils - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^checkout.php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^end_transaction.php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^cms.php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^html - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^keyclient - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^paypal - [L,NC]


# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is not for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Do you think it's a problem with this?

Thanks.

Comment: How can .htaccess end with `RewriteCond` line

Comment: Can you explain me how to make that process? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a filesystem permission problem: your files belong to the wrong user and some are not readable for the webserver.

To verify if this is the case, just find one page that temporarily gets a 403 error and see if reloading changes anything. If not, then it's not a permission thing.

Also, you might find more details in your server's log file. (error log and access log)

Comment: I found a page from the error 403, recharging does not give me more than the error. We say that comes and goes.Now I'm trying to change all the privileges and then rechecking. Thank You.

Comment: I set all files and all folders privileges of writing and reading, but I always have the same problem...

Comment: could you possibly name a url where this 403 error always occurs?

Comment: also, by the way (as you might want to know): If I try opening your page  http://accademiazeropiu.it  is see nothing but a white screen and the error message "Language not found". (My Operating System and my Browser are configured to be in English and my IP is from Germany)

you might want to fallback to the default language content in that case. (users that don't speak italian might still be able to understand that language. and maybe equally important: google will probably not be able to access and index your page if you give no content for english locale.)

Comment: Excuse me for "Language not Found" was my mistake, I have now solved. I report here a link where the problem happens, I want to clarify that it does not happen always the thing is purely random.